# UPDATE query based on a saved SELECT query in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Using a UPDATE query, is it possible to reference to a stored select query?

I'd like to accomplish something like this:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE ... IN [MY_STORED_PROCEDURE]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something on these lines:

```
UPDATE ...
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MyStoredProc)
```

Depending on your set up, a join may also be possible. You can add stored queries to the query design window, but you do not always end up with an updatable query, it usually depends on your indexes.

Comment: Howso? How does it depends on the indexes?
Like you said, I got it working, but nothing updates even though the query SELECT id FROM MyStoredProc is working.

Comment: An updatable query using a join can depend on whether there is a unique index. Try creating a query using a join on your table and the save query and see if any records are returned to check if there is anything to update.

Comment: I see. But seams more likely to run into trouble using a join. Do you have any idea why the 'SELECT id FROM MyStoredProc' is working (returns 3 rows) but not if I put it into a 'UPDATE .. WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM MyStoredProc)' (updates 0 rows)?

Comment: What happens when you use the actual id for your update? ie ID IN (1,2,3) ? Are you sure there are rows to update?

Comment: That is, are you sure the ids are matched?

Comment: Had a select that replaced the actual name of the column, which made it not match. Thank you very much for your help!