# db.Execute sql with reference to stored procedure

Tags: ms-access-2010

I've started to use `CurrentDb.Execute` to handle all my queries because it seams to most usable. The problem which I encountered when switching from DoCmd.RunSQL to CurrentDb.Execute is that references to stored procedures inside the SQL string isn't working.

```
UPDATE tbl SET x = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM [MyProc])
```

Does it need to be evaluated somehow, or is there something else that is wrong?

Comment: Is this pure MS Access or are you referencing another DB? In MS Access, the example above should work. You might like to post the full sql. If, for example, you are referencing a form, you may run into difficulties.

Comment: Not sure about your question. But the database is in a file on the local machine. Running the query it tells me there is insufficient parameters. And hence the only "special" reference i'm doing is to a stored procedure using []-brackets.

Comment: It would be best to post the sql.

Comment: The sql of MyProc as well :)

Comment: Ahh... there it was. Thank you very much. Is there a better way to evaluate the form data then Eval("Forms!Name!Box")?

Comment: Yes :) But it depends on where you are working. In MS Access you can refer to a form by name in a query, but elsewhere this will fail.

Comment: Those queries are in a script. But I'm using the MS Access GUI to visualize data for debugging. So I'm writing all select queries there, and then I do all the updating etc from code. Is there a better solution? Just started with Access/VBA a week ago. :-)

Comment: @Remou seems you two figured answer [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45660/discussion-between-mille-and-remou) - could you maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @molot, very well, but the answer has limited interest.

Comment: @Remou I know, but OP asked on meta to purge and delete chatroom, so posting answer here is a way to make sure it will not get lost. And seemingly "limited interest" answers helped me here a lot. Google is neat at finding obscure stuff that simply happens to meet what I'm doing ;) So for the sake of guys like me, in the future...

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can to refer to the form like so:

```
ssql = "SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE " & Me.Are & "=tbl2.col"
```

So MyProc can either be dropped or rewritten.

(See also [UPDATE query based on a saved SELECT query in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232196/update-query-based-on-a-saved-select-query-in-access) )